# mod_php missing from /etc/httpd/modules after installing it

Tags: apache-httpd, oracle-linux

I am using Oracle Linux 9 and I am getting the following error message when I am trying to start Apache : *Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration*

So, I have tried to install **mod_php** for Apache with the following procedure:

*yum install yum-utils*

*yum-config-manager --enable remi-modular*

*yum install mod_php*

But when I search for mod_php in /etc/httpd/modules I cannot see it. I am only seeing libphp.so and again when I am trying to start Apache I am getting the same error as the one written above.

Why Apache cannot start? Why does mod_php does not appear anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Since **EL-8**, php-fpm is used by default

mod_php is still provided, but need to switch apache to use old "*prefork*" MPM (bad for performance and security)

Since **EL-9**, mod_php is not more provided (in official Repository)

Using php-fpm, you can't use **php_value** in apache configuration, but you have to use it in [pool configuration](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php) (/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf for the default one)

You also cannot use **php_value** in .htaccess file, but you have to use the [.user.ini file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php).